# C# Updating/refresh gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

When I'm trying to update my gridview. The changes won't show up. But when I reopen the form it has changed. How can I make sure that it will update immediately (and show up). When I say:

```
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Fill(dt);
            userInformation.DataSource = dt;
```

It wil obviously fill the table. But than I have the information twice.

This is my code currently:

```
            DataTable dt;
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlCommandBuilder scb;

            //this is inside the constructor
            cmd = new SqlCommand("loadUserTable", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", this.username);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            userInformation.DataSource = dt;

            //this is a button (called save)
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(dt);
            userInformation.DataSource = dt;
```

Also I've tried refresh but that also doesn't do the job.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Are you using update panel in the page?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying da.Update. I'm making it in winforms.

Comment: Which gridview are you trying to update. From the code you posted, I see at least two, ritInformation and userInformation.

Comment: sorry, wrong copied I'm trying to update 1 gridview

Comment: How are you making changes to your gridView? Did you enter new values in your gridView but they went away after you clicked save?

Comment: Yes I had a window displayed before the gridview. When I saved in that window it didn't change in the gridview. But now it works. You first have to clear the table with dt.clear() and than fill it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you `Fill` an instance of `DataTable`, before you do so, you need to call the `Clear()` method on that `DataTable`.  If not, the `Fill` method just keeps adding on to that `DataTable`.

Comment: @tosorro I can't see how that fixes the issue of your updates not working. That only addresses the duplicate data problem. Unless there is extra code in "save" that you're not posting.

Comment: @tosorro Your comment on your question addresses what's going on here. Glad you found a solution! That said, you may want to rethink how you share/update data across multiple forms.

Comment: @iheanyi how would you do it?